# Select monitor for each workspace

Tags: linux, cinnamon

I have two monitor 17", I'd like know if is possible make this settings.

Ex:
Monitor 1 | Show WORKSPACE 1
Monitor 2 | Show WORKSPACE 2

I tryed in display settings, I not found this option that I desire.

Maybe some software can do this ?

My OS: Linux Mint 18.1 Cinnamon 64-bit

Comment: @jww I'm sorry, I did not know, but you're so boring.

Comment: Why not move the question to a site where it is on-topic? You can flag the question and ask the moderators move it so you don't have to delete it on one site and create it on another site. It also resets the question's score. For whatever reasons, the Stack Exchange network does not allow you to migrate it yourself. Also see [Author initiated migration to other SE sites?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254851)

Comment: "You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it. For more information, visit the help center." @jww

Comment: anyway, I got my a good answer, thanks @Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to properly configure `xrandr` to recognize the monitors you have.

Linux is always DIY, so thats how you're going to have to achieve this.

Here is a tutorial on how to configure dual monitors by editing your `xorg.conf` and `xrandr` settings.

Hope this helps...

https://www.maketecheasier.com/how-to-setup-dual-monitors-with-xrandr/

Comment: Thanks, I'll try later